# How to save value from Observer android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a `ROOM` database where I get values ​​from.

I am using an `Observer` to get the data, however there is a problem. I have a global variable `availability` in my `Fragment` that I want to store the value in because I need to work with this variable in many parts of the code. However `Observer`, for some reason, does not store any data into this variable.

Code:

```
private var availability = 0

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentCoursesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    viewModel.availability.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        availability = it
    }

    return binding.root
}
```

The reason why I need such a global variable, as I said earlier, is to use it in other parts of the code, since the state of other UI elements depends on it, which also depends on other `Observers`.

How to be in such a situation?

Comment: This code looks fine although it is odd to store LiveData’s value directly in a variable since it will be changing. How are you determining that data is not being copied to the property?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I used logcat to look at the value inside and outside of the observer. It turned out that the value, for some reason, is not copied there

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the observer, since there is only one line, it will break before the change takes place. If you put a breakpoint outside the observer, it will be before `onCreateView` has returned yet, so it will not have any values published yet. In either case, you are checking too early for there to have been any changes yet. Remember than an observer is reacting to changes that will be coming in the future, repeatedly, and not at the moment that you register the observer.

Comment: Please add what is availability in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in two forms

1. Using jetpack compose
2. Using the ordinary

**Answer 1/2**, If you built your app with Jetpack Compose, this would work **in only a single line** by doing this:

```
    private val availability = 0

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentCoursesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    //this single line
        availability = viewModel.availability.collectAsState(initial=0).value
        

    return binding.root
}
```

**Answer 2/2** when you didn't use compose, **You only have a choice to work within the context in the curly braces**

```
    viewModel.availability.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            availability = it
    //TODO: in only this context.... Call all
 //Functions, objects, Variables, classes that you want to use the up-to-date value of availability from here 
        }
```

Values outside that context will not acquire upto date data since the compiler will assign values basing on context